# Как из одномерного массива сделать двумерный?

Tags: python, list, список

У меня есть массив:

```
b = ['Hi!', 'My name is Ivan.', 'I am beginner programier...']
```

Из него хочу сделать такой:

```
b = [['Hi!'], ['My name is Ivan.'], ['I am beginner programier...']]
```

То есть массив, где каждый элемент это массив.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vanilla Python:

```
b = list(map(lambda x: [x], b))
```

или:

```
b = [[x] for x in b]
```

Numpy:

```
import numpy as np   #  pip install numpy

b = np.asarray(b).reshape(-1, 1)
```

---

результат:

```
In [36]: b
Out[36]:
array([['Hi!'],
       ['My name is Ivan.'],
       ['I am beginner programier...']], dtype='<U27')

In [37]: b.shape
Out[37]: (3, 1)
```

Comment: спасибо 
с лямбдой круто вышло :)